# GCP cloud function is unable to connect to GCP SQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

GCP Cloud functions use local Socket to connect to SQL instance. But if i disable public ip of SQL instance , this connection does not work. (For security reasons , i want to disable public ip of SQL instance).

And also i tried to connect to SQL instance from Cloud function using private IP of SQL instance .  But it failed too.

So my question is, How can i make a connection from Cloud Function to GCP SQL instance when SQL instance's public IP is disabled?

My cloud function is written in "Python 3.7 (Beta)". And Database is postgres

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible answer should be that Cloud functions should have been able to connect to SQL instance using secure & private VPC connection (connected-vpc option)  . However it seems this option is possible using alpha version only as of now

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1-cnuWIpTjbSFAETbpHo4aqgCuhYCGk2qczxHZvNCmFI/viewform?edit_requested=true